# WASB with SAS token throws error: "Public access is not permitted on this storage account."

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, azure-blob-storage

I am not able to access a blob storage with private endpoint from apache spark. It is failing with error:

```
org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: 
Public access is not permitted on this storage account.
```

Same is working with Access Keys but not with SAS tokens. I have used below conf setting as given in the documentation:

```
sparkSession.conf().set(
  "fs.azure.sas.<CONTAINER_NAME>.<STORAGE_ACCOUNT>.blob.core.windows.net", 
  <BASE-64_ENCODED_SASTOKEN>)
```

I have also tried like below but the result is same as above mentioned ("Public access is not permitted on this storage account.")

```
sparkSession.sparkContext().conf().set(
  "fs.azure.sas.<CONTAINER_NAME>.<STORAGE_ACCOUNT>.blob.core.windows.net", 
  <BASE-64_ENCODED_SASTOKEN>)
```

I tried with access keys and it works but with SAS tokens apache spark seems to have a problem in accessing the blob storage private endpoints. It works well with the public access but not with private endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having a similar issue. On the Storage Account, under Settings > Configuration, enable the "Allow Blob public access" option:

[image]

This does not mean your account is public, only that containers and blobs may be set to public. It seems as though SAS tokens are managed as public, which makes sense in a way since anyone with the link can access the item(s).